# Color a ROW and still be able to select other Rows after it?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am having a real big problem and its so big because I searched everywhere but I cant find a solution.

I want to color a whole row into yellow forever. Yellow Row indicates that the Customer has already paid. After that, I still need to be able to Select Rows (they selected ones should be blue, the others white) to do other things with them (Update, Remove, etc). But it all kinda just gets messed up and in the end, every Row I just press gets yellow and I dont understand why. I am using a Custom tableCellRenderer.

**Do I have to proof every time I press onto a row if that row has paid or not? and then color it in either yellow or blue?**

```
teilnehmertable.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new MyTableCellRender(teilnehmertable.getSelectedRow()));
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://10.0.0.1:3306/askoedb", "name", "pw");
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            rs1 = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT bezahlt FROM askoedb.teilnehmer");
            while (rs1.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs1.getString(1));
                if (rs1.getString(1) != null) {
                    if (selectedRow != -1) {
                        if (row == selectedRow) {
                            setForeground(Color.black);
                            setBackground(Color.yellow);
                        } else {
                            setForeground(Color.black);
                            setBackground(Color.white);
                        }
                    }
                    setText(value != null ? value.toString() : "");
                } else {
                    if (selectedRow != -1) {
                        if (row == selectedRow) {
                            setForeground(Color.white);
                            setBackground(Color.blue);
                        } else {
                            setForeground(Color.black);
                            setBackground(Color.white);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return this;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        return this;
    }
```

Comment: Manuel  you should provide a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org). Valid code demonstrating the problem. What have you tried.

Comment: Please provide the code for your Custom tableCellRenderer, the issue may be in the logic for it. Most likely the yellow forever should be some condition like "boolean paid" and not based on selection/row position.

Comment: JTable uses the same cell renderer over and over for each cell.  My guess, without being able to see your code, is that you're setting the background to yellow if the paid condition is true, but you didn't write an `else` block to set the renderer's color to the JTable's default background when the paid condition is false.

Comment: You `TableModel` will also have to store the `paid` status of each row.

Comment: I have edited the code. I just need some help on what the method getTableCellRenderComponent exactly does. I have read the documentation but it just doesnt tell me what I need. If I set table.setDefaultRender, how many times does the method get called? If I make a system.out.println, i get it like 100 times and i dont know why...

Comment: @ManuelAndres, `I searched everywhere but I cant find a solution.` - I provided you with a working example very similar to your requirement. `i get it like 100 times and i dont know why...` - I also explained that. The renderer is called every time a cell is rendered. When the table is first displayed it gets called for every row/column. Then when selection changes it gets called for every column in the rows where selection was changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to proof every time I press onto a row if that row has paid or not? and then color it in either yellow or blue?

Yes the row is rendered every time it is selected/deselected.

See [Table Row Rendering](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) for one approach that allows you to color an entire row based a value in a specific column.